# How to wipe data of AVD that is not booted

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've got the command to boot a sim and wipe the data

```
emulator -avd myemu -wipe-data
```

but how can I wipe the data of the sam AVD without booting it?

How about all AVDs which are not booted?

Answer (score 0):

You can wipe the emulator's data using the *Wipe user data* option when starting the emulator from the Android AVD Manager. If you are using the command line SDK instead, you can switch to the GUI tools [as detailed on this page](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/), which is more convenient than dealing with the command line arguments.